# Android: About the Remote Service communication via Process

Tags: android, service, process

First let me show my puzzle by a diagram

```
Application1 ----> Remote  ----> Application2
Process      <---- Service <---- Process
```

What I want to know if a remote service can perform as a channel that different application processes can communicate via this remote service.

I tried some demos. But it seems only RemoteService-single Application communication in different process. I can't try out two different applications communicating via RemoteServices.

I think this RemoteService act as a "GlobalService" and any Applicaiton can bind to it. And it should be a singleton RemoteService. If it's killed, it will be created by one of the applications, and other applications detect it alive, then won't create it twice.

Can this model be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use AIDL(Android interface definition language) to achieve your task. If you use it your

> **Process <---- Service <---- Process**
>  model will be like
>  
>   **Process <---- Process <---- Process**
>  because you require a process for your service.
>  Following are the important links for AIDL:
>  http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html
>  http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/invoking-services.html